# Return Status Code 410 with Symfony for Google Bot

Tags: php, symfony, http-status-code-410

As Google Bot is visiting one of our websites with wrong URLs, I constantly get Server errors bugging me as Administrator (The reason is that I accidentially submitted a wrong sitemap 3 months ago. Yes, I have resubmitted, deleted, resubmitted several times but it's still visiting).

I now learned in the Google Forum that using a 410 response will make the goggle bot stop visiting.

Does anyone have an idea how to send a 410 response from Symfony2? If that won't work, I would also be fine with a plain PHP-solution.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html#method_sendHeaders

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this, seems to work. Will update once I learn whether it has a long-term effect

```
   $response = new Response();
   $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
   $response->setStatusCode(410);
   return $response;}
```

Comment: Hi, we want to implement this, did it had a long-term effect? I guess it's hard to really know.

Answer (score 0):

That's basically the same as the previous answer, but using the a Twig 404 template (you must create) and a one liner:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

...

return new Response($this->renderView('TwigBundle:Exception:error404.html.twig'), Response::HTTP_GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
$response = new Response();
$response->setStatusCode(410);
return $this->render('twig_template_uri', ['key'=> $value, ...], $response);
```

I am using this in a controller when the data exists but "isActive = false" for instance

Answer (score 0):

You can use GoneHttpException

```
throw new GoneHttpException();
```